# Return Stripe Session.id from Django view

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

Im trying to implement Stripe Payment API into my django site.
From my cart.html page I have a button that goes to my checkoutView and creates Products and Prices from the cart:

```
def checkout(request):
    customer = request.user.customer
    order = Order.objects.get(customer=customer)
    items = order.orderitem_set.all()
    prices =[]
    for item in items:
        product =stripe.Product.create(
            name = item.product.name,
            description= item.product.description
        )
        price = stripe.Price.create(
            product= product.id,
            unit_amount=int(item.product.price.amount)*100,
            currency='gbp',
        )
        prices.append(price.id)

    line_items=[]
    for item, price in zip(items,prices):
            line_items.append({'price':price,'quantity':item.quantity}),
    session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
    payment_method_types=['card'],
    line_items=line_items,

    mode='payment',
    success_url='http://127.0.0.1:8000/SUCCESS/?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
    cancel_url='http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
    )
```

I then have to redirect to Stripes checkout [Docs here.](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/accept-a-payment#redirect-checkout) I would like to call this from a button on my cart but im not sure how to get the SessionId from the view BACK to the template and call this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you would pass the Session ID into your view, or use an asynchronous request to create the session from your backend. For example:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

def build_checkout_session(customer):
  # Use your existing code to create Products, Prices, etc...
  session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(…)
  return session

def checkout_view(request):
  session = build_checkout_session(customer=request.user.customer)
  return render(request, 'checkout.html', {'session_id': session.id})
```

Then, in your checkout.html:

```html
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  const sessionID = "{{ session_id }}";

  const stripe = Stripe("pk_test_12345"); // Put your publishable key here
  document.getElementById('checkoutButton').addEventListener('click' (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    stripe.redirectToCheckout({sessionId: sessionID});
  });
</script>
```

I wanted to note also that rather than create Products and Prices each time, you can pass ad-hoc data into the Checkout Session as shown here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/accept-a-payment#creating-ad-hoc-prices

Comment: JUST figured it out but this is cleaner so thank you so much! Works a treat

Comment: how did you resolve the url aspect of this? I am struggling with the regex aspect of accepting the session id url